# Understanding K&R's getint() (Chapter 5: Pointers & Arrays, Exercise 1)?

Tags: c, input

I'm a novice programmer who's self-studying C through K&R. I don't understand the design of their function getint(), which converts a string of digits into the integer it represents. I'll ask my question then post the code below.

If getch() returns a non-digit character that's not a '-' or '+', it pushes this non-digit character back onto the input with ungetch(), and returns 0. So, if getint() is called again, getch() will just return that same non-digit character that was pushed back, so ungetch() will push it back again, etc. The way I understand it (which could be wrong), the function breaks completely if it's passed any non-digit character.

The exercise doesn't have you fix this. It asks to fix the fact that a '-' or '+' followed by a non-digit is a valid representation of 0.

What exactly am I missing here? Did they design getint() to make an infinite loop if the input is anything other than 0-9? Why?

Here's their code for getint() [edit] with main calling getint():

```
int getint(int *);

int main()
{
        int n, array[BUFSIZE];
        for (n = 0; n < BUFSIZE && getint(&array[n]) != EOF; n++)
                     ;
        return 0;
}

 int getch(void);
 void ungetch(int);

int getint(int *pn)
{
        int c, sign;
        while (isspace(c = getch())
                ;
        if (!isdigit(c) && c != EOF && c != '+' && c != '-') {
                ungetch(c); //this is what i don't understand
                return 0;
        }

        sign = (c == '-') ? -1 : 1;

        if (c == '-' || c == '+')
                c = getch();
        for (*pn = 0; isdigit(c); c = getch())
                *pn = 10 * *pn + (c - '0');
        *pn *= sign;
        if (c != EOF)
                 ungetch(c);
        return c;
}

int buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufp = 0;

int getch(void)
{
        return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c)
{
        if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
                printf("ungetch: can't push character\n");
        else
                buf[bufp++] = c;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that calls `getint`?

Comment: just added main() to fill an array with getint(). thanks

Comment: I think it's in case you want to use `getch` to get a mix of numerical and non-numerical input. If you have a bunch of non-numerical input, repeatedly caling `getint` would gobble it up one character at a time without the `ungetch`.

Comment: i still don't really understand. doesn't adding ungetch() mean getint() never gets past the first non-numerical character?

Comment: It is an error condition.  But the function was not designed to return an error indication.  That is a pretty bad practice you would not contemplate in a real program.  Avoiding to overwhelm the reader with too many details was surely the goal.  Just in case, when your array is filled with zeros then you know what happened :)

Comment: @HansPassant the function is returning a zero in that case indicating that it didn't read. How is it not handling the error?

Comment: It is not quite obvious to me what it is supposed to return when the user types "0".  Well, it has been too many decades ago.

Answer (score 1):

As it is currently written, `getint()` function is trying to read an integer from user input and puts it into `*pn`.

1. If user inputs a positive or negative number(with a sign or without it), *pn gets updated to that number and getint() returns some positive number (the next character after the number).
2. If user inputs a non valid number, `*pn` is not updated and `getint()` returns `0` (meaning it failed).

   > the function breaks completely if it's passed any non-digit character.

   That's right. All subsequent calls to `getint()` will fail as the last character was passed to `ungetch()`. What you understand is correct.

   But this is how `getint()` is supposed to handle garbage input. It'll simply reject it and return 0 (meaning it failed). It is not the responsibility of `getint()` to take care of non-integer input and prepare fresh input for next read. It is not a bug.

   The only bug is that a '-' or '+' followed by a non-digit is currently being considered as a valid representation of 0. Which is left to reader as an exercise.
3. If user inputs `EOF`, `*pn` is not updated (multiplied by 1) and `getint()` returns `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning is similar to `scanf` not consuming characters that don't match the conversion specifier - you don't want to consume something that isn't part of a valid integer, but *may* be part of a valid string or other type of input.  `getint` has no way of knowing whether the input it rejects is part of an otherwise valid non-numeric input, so it has to leave the input stream the same way it found it.